# C# parsing special Character with HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, html, parsing, special-characters

I am parsing a HTML site to use the Data in a C# Client.
unfortunately my HTTPresponse is messing up all special characters (like french names) and replaces them with Question Marks "?".
what can I do to remedy my Problem?

Here is My Code:

```
private void LoadData()
{
    String strBaseURL = @"http://here_goes_the_url.com/";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
    WebRequest.Create(strBaseURL);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)
    request.GetResponse();
    Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();

    string tempString = null;
    int count = 0;

    do
    {
        count = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        if (count != 0)
        {
            tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, count);
            sb.Append(tempString);
        }
    }
    while (count > 0);
    result = sb.ToString();
}
```

I tried to change the encoding but that results in nothing :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use something else than ASCII.

Try this, for example:

```
tempString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf, 0, count);
```

The reason is that the [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) encoding only covers a 127-bit character set whereas [UTF8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) covers all characters in the [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) character set.

Comment: That worked! Thanks very much, I tried with UniCode and UTF32 first but that didnt Work, UTF8 and I can see all characters :)